# Digitized Voice over piezoelectric speaker

Tags: atmega, piezoelectric-effect

My objective is too implement a security system that is triggered when someone breaks the IR beam. This IR beam has a digital output pin. Which goes high (5V) when the beam is broken. This signal then goes to an ATMEGA328 microcontroller.

My question is once the Atmega 328 receives the high input from the IR beam, I would like to know if there's a way in which I can make the piezoelectric speaker (powered from 5V) output a phrase instead of just making the normal buzzing sound. The phrase will be something like "intruder detected".

Can I digitize this phrase using the atmega328 and then output straight to the piezoelectric speaker?

Comment: How fast can the ATMEGA produce the equivalent of an analogue sample of speech? Have you looked into this at all or are you just expecting someone to draw it out for you?

Comment: Yes,if the speaker is up to it. Try it with WAV files from a PC first.

Comment: @Andyaka I got a 16 and 32MHz external crystal oscillator. "have I looked at this..... or just expecting someone to draw it out for you?". Well to answer that, since I don't know where to start I can't do something if I don't know what to do. All I know is the high level idea of the objective. I would therefore appreciate any assistance that provides a way that draws it for me but not in a way were I just expect everything to be for me. I would also like to know how this is achieved so I would also like to contribute towards the solution as well.

Comment: How quickly can you output successive PWM values?

Comment: @Andyaka do you mean in terms of the rise and fall times of the PWM?

Comment: No I don't. How quickly can you output one full cycle of PWM or, what is the time difference between successive PWM outputs?

Comment: Andy is asking you about the maximum **frequency** of your PWM output, and about how many cycles of the PWM signal are required to change the duty factor (usually just 1).

Answer (score -3):

for voice, you need changing tones and sometimes multiple simultaneous tones. For example, the word "fire" has two harmonically-related tones that BOTH rise as the "EEYYEE" phonem is spoken.

Your piezo must do that.